# Why does a more exact match gets a lower score than a less exact match in a full text search in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data which I am search from elastic search as it provides better full text search in comparison to MongoDB. But I am facing some problems and one of that is :

My data saved in elasticsearch like :

```
[{
   "word": "tidak berpuas hati",
   "type": "NEGATIVE",
   "score": -0.3908697916666666
  },{
   "word": "berpuas hati",
   "type": "POSITIVE",
   "score": 0.65375
  },{
   "word": "hati",
   "type": "POSITIVE",
   "score": 0.6
  },{
   "word": "tidak",
   "type": "NEGATIVE",
   "score": 0.6
}]
```

But when I search a `saya tidak berpuas hati` sentence in this data. I get response something like this :

```
"hits": [
 {
    "_index": "sentiment",
    "_type": "ms",
    "_id": "8SPiimYBKsyQt_Jg1VYa",
    "_score": 8.838576,
    "_source": {
       "word": "berpuas hati",
       "type": "POSITIVE",
       "score": 0.65375
    },
    "highlight": {
       "word": [
          "<em>berpuas</em> <em>hati</em>"
       ]
    }
 },
 {
    "_index": "sentiment",
    "_type": "ms",
    "_id": "PiPiimYBKsyQt_Jg1U4U",
    "_score": 8.774891,
    "_source": {
       "word": "tidak berpuas hati",
       "type": "NEGATIVE",
       "score": -0.3908697916666666
    },
    "highlight": {
       "word": [
          "<em>tidak</em> <em>berpuas</em> <em>hati</em>"
       ]
    }
 },
 {
    "_index": "sentiment",
    "_type": "ms",
    "_id": "ByPiimYBKsyQt_Jg1VUZ",
    "_score": 5.045017,
    "_source": {
       "word": "hati",
       "type": "POSITIVE",
       "score": 0.6
    },
    "highlight": {
       "word": [
          "<em>hati</em>"
       ]
    }
  }
]
```

This is my query :

```
query = {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 20,
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "word": {
                        "query": term,
                        "operator": 'or',
                        "fuzziness": 'auto'
                    }
                }
            },
            "highlight": {
                "fields": {
                    "word": {}
                }
            }
        }
```

So the problem here is I don't understand why `tidak berpuas hati` score not come above to `berpuas hati`. When I change the value of `from` to `1` it start working for this sentence and stop for single words sentences.

Comment: How much data are we talking about in this example? How many shards does your ES index have? Have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/consistent-scoring.html maybe this explains your experience.

Comment: I have around 25,000 documents and  "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "skipped": 0,
      "failed": 0
   }

Comment: I think what you want is Match Phrase Query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch scores are calculated per shard.

In this case the document with `berpuas hati` gets a higher score returned because it is somewhat more relevant inside it's shard than the document with `tidak berpus hati`.

The relevancy in Elasticsearch is decided through multiple factors, although here I would say that the reason is because there are more documents inside the `tidak berpuas hati`-shard that contain one (or more) of the terms `tidak` `berpuas`or `hati`, than in the `berpuas hati`-shard. Which is coincidence.

If you would try out the same query on an index that only contains these two documents, you would see that `berpuas hati` receives a score around 0,5 and `tidak berpuas hati` receives a score around 0,75.

You can find an explanation for how the scores came to stand by adding `"explain": true` to your query. The scoring algorithm is explained here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html

You might also want to read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html

Comment: - Thanks for great explanation, what I understand is, its better to have a single shard when we have less data.

Comment: If you don't plan on having more than 50GB of data (which is the recommended amount for a shard), yes.